# Can not run Sample 460, Introduction to Eventing and Event Mediator

Tags: wso2-esb

Currently i try to run this sample, but it doesn't work

[2014-01-23 14:34:22,519] ERROR - DefaultRealmService Tenant domain has not been set in CarbonContext
java.lang.NullPointerException: Tenant domain has not been set in CarbonContext
        at org.wso2.carbon.caching.impl.CacheManagerFactoryImpl.getCacheManager(CacheManagerFactoryImpl.java:79)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.TenantCache.getTenantCache(TenantCache.java:39)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.TenantCache.getValueFromCache(TenantCache.java:77)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.JDBCTenantManager.getTenant(JDBCTenantManager.java:224)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.JDBCTenantManager.getTenant(JDBCTenantManager.java:54)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.getTenantUserRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:159)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.core.internal.delivery.inmemory.InMemoryDeliveryManager.publish(InMemoryDeliveryManager.java:87)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.core.internal.EventPublisher.run(EventPublisher.java:56)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[2014-01-23 14:34:22,523] ERROR - EventPublisher Can not publish the message
org.wso2.carbon.event.core.exception.EventBrokerException: Can not access the user store manager
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.core.internal.delivery.inmemory.InMemoryDeliveryManager.publish(InMemoryDeliveryManager.java:109)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.core.internal.EventPublisher.run(EventPublisher.java:56)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Could you please explain me what's happen? And How can i solve that issuse ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug, look at : https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-2857